# Simplest redirect.php script gives 403 on WordPress, uploaded to site's root

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Just trying to make a simple innocent redirect script:

```
<?php header('Location: '. $_GET['url']);?>
```

I uploaded this to site's root. But when I visit `my-website.com/redirect.php?url=https://google.com`, I get 403. Could it be .htaccess related?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Briefly comment out your .htaccess rules and see if you still get the error.  But something like mod_security might be blocking this request.

Comment: Are you sure what your file have enough permissions? Try to increase it.

Comment: Permissions 777. Tried cleaning these .htaccess rules, didn't help. What is mod_security? It's a HostGator host, I'm seeing HostGator's default 403 page. Know something?

Answer (score 0):

It was a mod_security issues, I had to contact HostGator and ask them to disable this rotten pile of garbage.